# Set aspect ratio on semi-log subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to produce a figure with a total of 12 subplots. The x-axis is log, and the y axis is linear. How do I set the aspect ratio for each to 1?

```
plt.subplot(6, 2, 4)
plt.plot(H2SO3,h_km, label='H$_2$SO$_3$')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlim(10**-16)
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(6, 2, 11)
plt.plot(H2S,h_km, label='H$_2$S')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlim(10**-16)


plt.savefig('heelp.png')
plt.show()
```

I've only found solutions to loglog or linearlinear plots, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aspect ratio in semi-log plot with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866419/aspect-ratio-in-semi-log-plot-with-matplotlib)

Comment: @JohanC if it does then i'm not entirely sure how to apply it so that it works for me, sorry. If you could help me with that I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set or obtain both xlimits on the log scale, then use the log10 of the ratio of those limits to get the 'length' of the log axis which is analagous to the simple difference on a linear scale, and then further take the ratio of the two lengths.

```
ax = plt.subplot(6, 2, 4)
ax.plot(H2SO3,h_km, label='H$_2$SO$_3$')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlim(10**-18,10**-16)
plt.ylim(5,15) # for eg
plt.legend()
ax.set_aspect( np.log10(10**-16/10**-18) / (15-5) )
```