# Matplotlib - setting aspect ratio to equal when using semilogy or semilogx

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Is it possible to set the aspect ratio of semilogy or semilogx to "equal" without requiring to manually set the ticks (which is done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866419/aspect-ratio-in-semi-log-plot-with-matplotlib) solution)?

The example below is not able to do this and it generates a warning: "UserWarning: aspect is not supported for Axes with xscale=linear, yscale=log".

Note: with aspect ratio, I mean the ratio between x and y as they are displayed onscreen (px).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(10)
y = sorted(np.exp(10*np.random.rand(10)))  # generate arbitrary samples
plt.semilogy(x, y)
plt.axis('equal')  # This results in a user warning
plt.show()
```

Comment: Which version of matplotlib does you use? It works without any warning or error on matplotlib 3.3.0.

Comment: I should have updated it before posting the question because It indeed was an older version (3.1), the problem is resolved after updating. Thanks!